How to make the Link component wrap the entire summary element in Tailwindcss
I am following this section from the DaisyUI documentation, and I am building a sidebar, I have a problem that I want the collapsible item itself to be a link. It of course works however, the link element does not cover the entire button. I want the link to cover the entire button. look at the picture bellow:

Here is that section from my code (the administrators in the red color element):
import Link from 'next/link'

<details open>
  <summary className="bg-red-500">
    <Link href={href} className="bg-yellow-500">
      <div className="flex flex-row space-x-2">
        <i>{IconComponent && <IconComponent />}</i>
        <span>{t(labelKey)}</span>
      </div>
    </Link>
  </summary>
  <SidebarList items={subMenuItems} /> {/* Add a new administrator, the list bellow it */}
</details>


If the link covers the entirety of the <summary>, then when a user clicks to expand the <details>, they will be taken to the <Link>. This doesn't seem optimal if the user only wants to expand the submenu and not go to <Link>.
